# Oracle SQL to delete duplicate records based on columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with records:

```
DATE           NAME    AGE    ADDRESS
01/13/2014     abc     27     us
01/29/2014     abc     27     ma            <- duplicate
02/03/2014     abc     27     ny            <- duplicate
02/03/2014     def     28     ca
```

I want to delete the record number 2 and 3 since they are duplicates for record 1 based on name and age.  DATE column is a timestamp based from the record when it was added (sql date) and considered unique.

I found this sql but not sure if it will work and a bit concerned as the table has 2 million records and delting the wrong ones will be a bad idea:

```
SELECT A.DATE, A.NAME, A.AGE
  FROM table A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT B.DATE
             FROM table B
            WHERE B.NAME = A.NAME
          AND B.AGE = A.AGE);
```

There are many instance of this records so if someone can help me write a sql to delete this records?

Comment: which `DBMS` you are really using ???

Comment: In title you are telling oracle and mysql and sql-server as tags. Which one you really want?

Comment: I'm using oracle sql developer to view the tables. I just saw the sql statement and wonder if it will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+delete+duplicate+rows

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
DELETE FROM tbl t1
WHERE dt IN 
(
  SELECT t1.dt
  FROM   tbl t1
  JOIN   tbl t2 ON 
  (
    t2.name = t1.name
    AND t2.age=t1.age
    AND t2.dt > t1.dt
  )
);
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0bd0b/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table 
 where (date, name, age) not in ( select max( date ), name, age from table group by name, age )
```

Before delete verify with

```
select * from table 
 where (date, name, age) not in ( select max( date ), name, age from table group by name, age )
```

Answer (score 0):

[ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytical function will helpful (supported by Oracle and Sqlserver).
The logic of assigning a unique ordered number for each row inside a partition, needs to be implemented carefully inside ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT A_TABLE.*,
        ROW_NUMBER ()
        OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, AGE
              ORDER     BY DATE  DESC)
           seq_no
FROM A_TABLE;
```

Then you may use the result for delete operation:

```
Delete A_TABLE 
where DATE,NAME,AGE IN 
(
   SELECT DATE,NAME,AGE FROM
   (
      SELECT A_TABLE.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, AGE
              ORDER     BY DATE DESC)
               seq_no
      FROM A_TABLE;
   ) 
   WHERE seq_no != 1
 )
```